# Mapping $w=\frac{z}{1+z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let  $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ z=x+iy$  $, \,\,\,\,\,\ w=u+iv$

I need to find the curve in the plane $u,v$ that mapped by the function $w=\frac{z}{1+z}$ the line $x=-\frac 1 2 $

**My attempt:**

$$w=\frac{x+yi}{1+x+yi}=\dots =\underbrace{\bigg(\frac{x+y^2}{1+2x+x^2+y^2}\bigg)}_{=u}+\underbrace{\bigg(\frac{y}{1+2x+x^2+y^2}\bigg)}_{=v}i$$

After placing $x=-\frac 1 2:$

$$u=\frac{-1/4+y^2}{3/4+y^2}\,\,\,,\,\,\,v=\frac{y}{1/4+y^2}$$

> I'm stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your calculation, it should be
$$
u=\frac{-1/4+y^2}{1/4+y^2}\,\,\,,\,\,\,v=\frac{y}{1/4+y^2}
$$
and with a good eye one can spot that
$$
   u^2 + v^2 = 1 \, ,
$$
so that the image is a circle with center at the origin and radius $1$.

---

An easier way is to use the fact that $T(z)=\frac{z}{1+z}$ is a 
[*Möbius transformation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) and therefore maps lines or circles to lines
or circles, and locally preserves angles.

From $T(-1/2) = -1$ and $T(\infty) = 1$ together with the fact that $T$ maps the (extended)
real axis onto itself, it follows that the image
of the line $x = -1/2$
 is  a circle
through $-1$ and $1$ which intersects the real axis at an right  angle.